# Colocación del footer de una página web

Tags: html, css

tengo **dos problemas con el footer** de la página web siguiente:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Papelería María</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        
        /* reset css */
        html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul, li, pre, code, address, variable, form, fieldset,    blockquote {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
        }
        table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
        td, th, caption { font-weight: normal; text-align: left; }
        img, fieldset { border: 0; }
        ol { padding-left: 1.4em; list-style: decimal; }
        ul { padding-left: 1.4em; list-style:square; }
        q:before, q:after { content:''; }
        a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        /* final reset */
        
        body{
            background:
                url("imagenes/lapices_izquierda.jpg") left top repeat-y,
                url("imagenes/lapices_derecha.jpg") right top repeat-y;
            background-color: #5EB6DB;
        }
        
        #cabecera{
            width: 45em;
            background-color: #5EB6DB;
            margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
            border-radius: 40%;
            border: solid #000 3px;
            
        }
        
        #titulo{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #FFF;
            width: 13em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            
        }
        
        #nav{
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }
        
        #nav li{
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px 30px 0 0;
        }
        
        #nav li a{
            border: 2px solid #CCC;
            background-color: #EEE;
            padding: 2px 7px;
            color: #666;
        }
        
        #nav li a:hover{
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        
        footer a{
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #F40A0E;
        }
        
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="cabecera">
    
    <p id="titulo">PAPELERÍA MARÍA</p>
    
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="Index.html" id="pagina_1">Página_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_2.html" id="pagina_2">Página_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_3.html" id="pagina_3">Página_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_4.html" id="pagina_4">Página_4</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <p>Cualquier duda, consulte a través de <a href="mailto:papeleriamaria@gmail.com">papeleriamaria@gmail.com</a></p>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Este código consta de código HTML con una hoja de estilos CSS interna. El reset CSS es de otro programador, pero no toca el footer. He leído que la etiqueta footer debería tener, de manera predeterminada, una **colocación a pie de página** (lo que viene a ser abajo del todo de la página). Ahora bien, a mí me aparece como un párrafo más en el body. ¿Por qué?

**Otro problema es el color** del correo que aparece en el footer. Debería ser rojo, pero sale negro. ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto al footer no es como piensas, esta fuera del body y tiene su propio espacio, pero no va a estar automáticamente abajo del todo, para ello debes primero estructurar mejor los bloques para que el tenga su espacio definido. De forma resumida, debes usar el css mejor para la colocación de los bloques.

Lo segundo a comentar es que lo que tu has colocado arriba que es de otro programador, como tu dices, no se modifica el footer pero si los tipo `a` que sean `link`,`visitado`,`el raton pase por encima`. Hay dos formas, uno es cambiar tu lo de arriba y en vez de que sea negro sea de otro color o puedes hacer lo que yo te he puesto, que es añadirle un `!important`, aun que esto es una mala practica, pero como no se si te interesa de la forma anteriormente comentada o esta, yo te lo añado, `!important` lo que hace es que le da un poco igual a lo que tenga por encima, se aplicara esto primero.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Papelería María</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        
        /* reset css */
        html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul, li, pre, code, address, variable, form, fieldset,    blockquote {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
        }
        table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
        td, th, caption { font-weight: normal; text-align: left; }
        img, fieldset { border: 0; }
        ol { padding-left: 1.4em; list-style: decimal; }
        ul { padding-left: 1.4em; list-style:square; }
        q:before, q:after { content:''; }
        a:link, a:visited, a:hover{
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        /* final reset */
        
        body{
            background:
                url("imagenes/lapices_izquierda.jpg") left top repeat-y,
                url("imagenes/lapices_derecha.jpg") right top repeat-y;
            background-color: #5EB6DB;
        }
        
        #cabecera{
            width: 45em;
            background-color: #5EB6DB;
            margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
            border-radius: 40%;
            border: solid #000 3px;
            
        }
        
        #titulo{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #FFF;
            width: 13em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            
        }
        
        #nav{
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }
        
        #nav li{
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0px 30px 0 0;
        }
        
        #nav li a{
            border: 2px solid #CCC;
            background-color: #EEE;
            padding: 2px 7px;
            color: #666;
        }
        
        #nav li a:hover{
            background-color: #333;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        
        footer a{
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ff0004 !important;
        }
        
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="cabecera">
    
    <p id="titulo">PAPELERÍA MARÍA</p>
    
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="Index.html" id="pagina_1">Página_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_2.html" id="pagina_2">Página_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_3.html" id="pagina_3">Página_3</a></li>
        <li><a href="pagina_4.html" id="pagina_4">Página_4</a></li>
    </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    <footer>
        <p>Cualquier duda, consulte a través de <a href="mailto:papeleriamaria@gmail.com">papeleriamaria@gmail.com</a></p>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```